# covr::package_coverage reports "No such file or directory"

Tags: r, testing, package, code-coverage, covr

I'm trying to see the code coverage of [sumbose/iRF](https://github.com/sumbose/iRF), so I did a `git clone`, started an R session inside of the directory, and

```
> library(covr)
> package_coverage()
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages(repos = NULL, lib = tmp_lib, pkg$path,  :
  installation of package ‘/private/tmp/iRF’ had non-zero exit status
2: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/private/var/folders/ny/f06ns0d568bgf6s559z8j_9m0000gn/T/RtmpAr8dLV/R_LIBS168866d1ef32f/iRF/R/iRF': No such file or directory
```

However, both `R CMD INSTALL iRF` and `install.packages('iRF', repos = NULL)` installs the package as expected.

Comment: did you find a solution or cause of the issue? I'm facing the same issue and I'm trying to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem too with a under-development package that is not installed. The error message has the path like this:

```
... /pkgname/R/pkgname': No such file or directory
```

where `pkgname` is the package name.

I used VS Code and called `covr::package_coverage()`, with the package folder as the working directory. I could consistently reproduce the error, and then I noticed that this error occurred if I called `devtools::load_all()` first.

I found that, for unknown reasons, this error disappeared if I started an R session and did not run `devtools::load_all()`. I did not need to (and maybe should not) load the package. `covr::package_coverage()` ran normally in that session without loading the package.

If I called `devtools::load_all()` after I called `covr::package_coverage()`, and then called `covr::package_coverage()` again, it would fail in the same session.

So I think the solution is simple, though a little bit counter intuitive:

Call `covr::package_coverage()` in a session that does not have the package loaded by `devtools::load_all()`.

I could call `covr::package_coverage()` several times in this session without problems. Changes I made to files were reflected correctly in the output of `covr::package_coverage()`, without the need to loading the package.

I used covr 3.5.1, R 4.2.0 in Windows.